# Tensorflow error while backpropagating through conv2d

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm facing a quite strange problem. I have a network which boils down to the following "central" code:

```py
# COSINE
proj = tf.multiply( proj, cosine_w, name = 'cosine-weighting' )

# PARKER
proj = tf.multiply( proj, parker_w, name = 'parker-weighting' )

# RAMLAK
s = config.proj_shape
proj = tf.reshape( proj, [ s.N, 1, s.H, s.W ] )
proj = tf.nn.conv2d(
       input = proj,
       filter = kernel,
       strides = [ 1, 1, 1, 1 ],
       padding = 'SAME',
       data_format = 'NCHW',
       name = 'ramlak-filter'
)
proj = tf.reshape( proj, config.proj_shape.toNCHW() )

# BACKPROJECTION
volume = backproject(
       projections = proj,
       # other arguments, which are attrs in the user defined op
)
```

I get some projection data in `proj`, which is a `N x H x W` tensor (where `N` is the number of projections). This data is then weighted in two stages and afterwards filtered with a 1-dimensional filter kernel. Note here, that I do not want different weights for the different projection images (the `N` dimension). Therefore I reshape `proj` to have a size of 1 in the channels dimension and "interpret" the projection images as different images from a batch. The backproject function is a custom tensorflow op implemented in c++/cuda with a registered gradient.

Everything works well for the forward-pass. But if I try to compute the gradient w.r.t the filter kernel, e.g. by

```
tf.gradients( volume, kernel, volume )
```

if get the following error:

```
NotFoundError (see above for traceback): No algorithm without scratch worked!
 [[Node: gradients/LAReconstructor_1/LAReconstructor/ramlak-filter_grad/Conv2DBackpropFilter = Conv2DBackpropFilter[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@LAReconstructor_1/LAReconstructor/ramlak-filter"], data_format="NCHW", padding="SAME", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](LAReconstructor_1/LAReconstructor/Reshape, gradients/LAReconstructor_1/LAReconstructor/ramlak-filter_grad/Shape_1, gradients/LAReconstructor_1/LAReconstructor/Reshape_1_grad/Reshape)]]
```

I tried to provide some minimal example that reproduces the error, but I could not reproduce it in such a minimal example. I have checked the gradient w.r.t to `proj` and it meets my expectations.

Does anyone have an idea what could go wrong here?

EDIT:

I have just found a minimal example which produces the same error:

```
import tensorflow as tf

proj = tf.Variable( tf.random_normal([720,1,400,600], stddev = 2) )
kernel = tf.Variable( tf.random_normal([1, 401, 1, 1], stddev = .5), trainable = True )
proj = tf.nn.conv2d(
    input = proj,
    filter = kernel,
    strides = [ 1, 1, 1, 1 ],
    padding = 'SAME',
    data_format = 'NCHW',
    name = 'ramlak-filter'
)
grad = tf.gradients( proj, kernel, proj )

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run( tf.global_variables_initializer() )
    print( sess.run( grad ) )
```

It seems to be related to the size of `proj`. If I change that to `[100, 1, 400, 600]`, the error disappears. But I actually need this large batch size. Any ideas?

Comment: Seems to me a `tensorflow` bug.

Comment: Do you really think this is a bug? Currently I think this might be some limit of CuDNN.. What do you mean? Otherwise I should report to Tensorflow..

Comment: May be its cuDnn... The reason i think its a `tensorflow limitation/issue` is when i tried forward path with a much bigger batch input [1500, 1, 400, 600]  there was no problem there. But backpropagation of a convolution network is also convolutional, so it should also work the way it does in forward. Your minimal example is a good test,  you should report to tensorflow. And by the way if your kernel size is defined the way it is in the example, you should try 1-d conv.

Comment: I have the same problem. I noticed that when I set my hyper parameters such that the resulting network is relatively small (fewer learnable parameters) the issue goes away. As soon as I set the network size larger, it reappears.

Comment: Did you raise it to Tensorflow? If not, I will. Let us know.

Comment: No, unfortunately I did not find a time slot for that yet.. So I'd be glad if you have time to do that. Can you please let me know when you've reported that? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ok, I just raised to Tensorflow: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/11327

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile this has been confirmed as a bug and raised to tensorflow: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/11327